# Is it possible to defined entire stages in a custom step?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently I defined shared pipelines in my library and pass them params from the Jenkinsfiles. I also modularize a lot of code into custom steps.

This works great and does everything I want:

```
// Jenkinsfile in repo just uses the shared pipeline
@Library('shared-lib') _
mySharedPipeline ([
    myParam = "sdlkfjlskdjfsd"
])


// The shared pipeline vars/mySharedPipeline.groovy
def call(Map config) {
    someVar = config.myParam
    someOtherVar = param.SomeUIParam

    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage ('one') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('two') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('three') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Custom steps are used by the shared pipeline vars/myCustomStep.groovy
def call(Map config) {
    derp = config.derp
    // do stuff
}
```

But want I'd like to do now is put entire stages into custom steps too. Is this possible? I can't figure out how to pass a stage into `stages{}` and *also* define stages in the usual way.

For example I want this (does not work):

```
// Custom steps vars/myCustomStep.groovy
def call(Map config) {
    derp = config.derp
    // do stuff
}

// Define a stage vars/mySharedStage.groovy
stage ('one') {
    steps {
        script { 
            // the shared stage will also use custom steps
            myCustomStep derp: someVar
        }
    }
}

// The shared pipeline vars/mySharedPipeline.groovy
def call(Map config) {
    someVar = config.myParam
    someOtherVar = param.SomeUIParam

    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {

          // I want to be able to just plug in a stage where ever I want like this
          mySharedStage

            stage ('one') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('two') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('three') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: `Expected a stage`
I even tried `mySharedStage.call()` and I still get this error

I added the groovy label, but fyi Jenkins runtime is very restrictive so many groovy-isms will not work here.

## Edit

Another attempt to nest a stage in a custom step and reference inside the pipeline block, this also throws `Expected a stage`

```
// vars/mySharedStage.grooy
def call(Map config) {
    stage ('My Shared Stage') {
        steps {
            echo "derps"
        }
    }
}

// inside vars/mySharedPipeline.groovy
        stages {
            stage ('one') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }

          mySharedStage

            stage ('two') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
```

## Edit

Just as an experiment I instantiated a `Stage` object in raw groovy code. I could create a `Stage` object without issue, but adding it in between other stage blocks raised the same error. I want to do both interchangeably- use the stage closures AND plugin a shared stage wherever I want.

```
def call(Map config) {

    String stageName = "my stage"
    StepsBlock stepsBlock = new StepsBlock()
    Agent myAgent = new Agent({})
    PostStage myPost = new PostStage(["myPostStage": new StepsBlock()])
    StageConditionals myWhen = new StageConditionals({})
    Tools tools = new Tools(["my tools": {}])
    Environment myEnvironment = new Environment(new EnvironmentResolver(), new EnvironmentResolver())
    Boolean failFast = true
    StageOptions myOptions = new StageOptions(["xxx":{}], ["yyy":{}])
    StageInput input = new StageInput("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", [])
    Stages myStages = new Stages([])
    Parallel myParallel = new Parallel([])
    Environment anotherEnvironment = new Environment(new EnvironmentResolver(), new EnvironmentResolver())

    // https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-model-definition/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/model/Stage.html
    // I can at least instantiate an object
    Stage myStage = new Stage (
            stageName,
            stepsBlock,
            myAgent,
            myPost,
            myWhen,
            tools,
            myEnvironment,
            failFast,
            myOptions,
            input,
            myStages,
            myParallel,
            anotherEnvironment,
    )

    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage ('one') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }

          // throws the same "expected stage" error
          myStage

            stage ('two') {
                steps {
                    script { 
                        myCustomStep derp: someVar
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sticked too much to declarative pipeline. Although you are wisely trying to execute as closure, `stages` function must be requiring the `stage` function inside. I didn't check it but most probably it should be easy to find in the source code (I think you see it that stages is just a function with 1 big closure argument).

Anyway, if you want to make it modular, I would go more into scripted pipeline like this:

```
node {
    stageFirst()
    stageSecond()
}

def stageFirst(){
  stage('First'){
  echo "Inside first stage"
  }
}

def stageSecond(){
  stage('Second'){
  echo "Inside second stage"
  }
}
```

You can place these functions inside libraries and access them in various pipelines.